# AngularJS Injection Error with models and services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, model, controller

I am getting the following error =

Unknown provider: UserModelProvider <- UserModel <- PropertyService

It is coming from me injecting the User model into a service .

What is odd, is that I am injecting it into a different service and it works fine there.

Works =

```
angular
    .module('app')        
    .service('JunkService', junkService);

junkService.$inject = ['$http', 'UserModel'];

function junkService($http, UserModel) {
```

Does NOT work =

```
angular
    .module('app')        
    .service('PropertyService', propertyService);

propertyService.$inject = ['$http', 'UserModel'];

function propertyService($http, UserModel) {
```

Both Junk and Property services are injected into their respective controllers, and it works in the Junk controller, but not the property one...

Any ideas?

The Model looks like this =

```
angular
    .module('app')        
    .factory('UserModel', userModel);

function userModel() {    
function User(firstName, lastName, role, organisation) {
        // Public properties, assigned to the instance ('this')
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
        this.organisation = organisation;
    }
return User;
}
})();
```

Comment: When are you linking/declaring each provider?  You still have to declare everything in the right order, so if JunkService comes before UserModel, it will throw that error.

Comment: I was thinking about declaration order, but as you can see above = they are the same.  In fact, other than the $http calls in he service, they are identical (both the Junk Service and the Property Service).  Order and everything = the same.   But it only injects in Junk, and not in Property...

Comment: Is this all in the same script, though?  If you include propertyService.js before userModel.js, this will happen.  I can't see above how you're actually including the scripts.  See @Marcidius's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial take on this is that the `<script>` tags in your index.html are in the wrong order.  Based on what you said IS working and what is not... you probably have the following:

```
<script src="../propertyService.js"></script>
<script src="../userModelProvider.js"></script>
<script src="../junkService.js"></script>
```

Where it should actually be reordered to have the userModelProvider (or whatever file contains this) loaded first prior to any dependent modules.

```
<script src="../userModelProvider.js"></script>
<script src="../propertyService.js"></script>
<script src="../junkService.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, well to be specific = I was nto loading User.js in the Property htnl at all :P

Comment: That tends to cause issues too :P.  Glad I could point you in the right direction.